# Export Rhythmbox ratings and play counts to ID3 tags

Tags: rhythmbox, mp3, clementine, id3

Is there a way to export Rhythmbox ratings to id3 tags, or migrate them in some other way? Maybe some EasyTag or Puddletag reads Rhythmbox config files? Or is there a utility to do migration?

Preferably also playcounts, although not sure if there is a playcount id3 field.

I'd like to migrate from Rhythmbox to another Linux mp3 player, as RB doesn't have some of the features I need. I'm looking at Clementine mainly for smaller footprint. Migrating ratings is holding me back.

Comment: I've wondered this for a long time and it's one of the reasons I never bothered with ratings & eventually switched to just using last.fm / songza

Comment: As someone with 20k+ songs rated meticulously over a ten-year period, I'm not about to let them go :P I actually just moved from Windows iTunes to Linux Rhythmbox, because that transition was pretty easy once I found the right method. I was hoping that open source mp3 players would be, well, more open, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: I understand the concern, and think this is an important question, and have tried to edit your title to get more attention for it.

Comment: I wish to do the same thing. Would be great to get a solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

this may be little late, but check out this tool:
https://github.com/shatterhand19/RhythmboxPOPM

The read me file in the repository explains in detail how to use the tool.

I had tested it on my computer, Ubuntu 16.14 and it works perfectly. If any problems post in the Issues section in the git hub repo.

Hope this helps someone reading this :)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about how to use this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)